# DIV Overflow DataSrc Hidden Scroll Not Working

Tags: html, overflow

Ok. I'm having an issue with a DIV not hiding the overflow-x of a dataSrc. How can I get the `overflow-x` to be hidden and `overflow-y` to scroll?

```
<style type="text/css">
#thediv { overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; border:1px solid #BFBFBF; width:540; height:400px; }
</style>
<div id='thediv' dataSrc="page.php"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate into another div

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper { overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; border:1px solid #BFBFBF; width:540; height:400px; }
</style>
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='thediv' dataSrc="page.php"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
overflow:auto
```

instead of

```
overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;
```